# How does ddply handle factors as "split" variables?

Tags: r, plyr

I have a data.frame with 20 columns. The first two are factors, and the rest are numeric. I'd like to use the first two columns as split variables and then apply the `mean()` to the remaining columns.

This seems like a quick and easy job for `ddply()`, however, the results for the output data.frame are not what I am looking for. Here is a minimal example with just one column of data:

```
Aa <- c(rep(c("A", "a"), each = 20))
Bb <- c(rep(c("B", "b", "B", "b"), each = 10))
x <- runif(40)
df1 <- data.frame(Aa, Bb, x)

ddply(df1, .(Aa, Bb), mean)
```

The output is:

```
  Aa Bb         x
1 NA NA 0.5193275
2 NA NA 0.4491907
3 NA NA 0.4848128
4 NA NA 0.4717899
Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(X[[1L]], ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

The warning is repeated 8 times, presumably once for each call to `mean()`. I'm guessing this comes from trying to take the mean of a factor. I could write this as:

```
ddply(df1, .(Aa, Bb), function(df1) mean(df1$x))
```

or

```
ddply(df1, .(Aa, Bb), summarize, x = mean(x))
```

both of which do work (not giving NAs), but I would rather avoid writing out 18 such `x = mean(x)` statements, one for each of my numeric columns.

Is there a general solution? I'm not wedded to `ddply` if there is a better answer elsewhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are reducing hte number of rows, you need to use `summarise`:

```
> ddply(df1, .(Aa, Bb), summarise, mean_x =mean(x) )
  Aa Bb    mean_x
1  a  b 0.3790675
2  a  B 0.4242922
3  A  b 0.5622329
4  A  B 0.4574471
```

It's just as easy to use aggregate in this instance. Let's say you had two variables:

```
> aggregate(df1[-(1:2)], df1[1:2], mean)
  Aa Bb         x         y
1  a  b 0.4249121 0.4639192
2  A  b 0.6127175 0.4639192
3  a  B 0.4522292 0.4826715
4  A  B 0.5201965 0.4826715
```

Comment: as for aggregating all but independent variables, try: aggregate(.~Aa+Bb, data=df1, mean)

Answer (score 2):

`ddply` supports negative indexing as well:

```
ddply(df1, .(Aa, Bb), function(x) mean(x[-(1:2)]))
```

Comment: That's really "[" that is handling those indices.

Comment: @Dwin - valid point. For practical purposes, is it 6 in one, 1/2 dozen in the other...or am I missing something else? I guess this relies on knowing the index of the columns you don't want to return the `mean` of ahead of time.....

Comment: If you don't want to "know" what numbers to negatively specify there is always grep(). Something like x[ -grep("Aa|Bb", names(x) ) ] should work.